# Dynamically adding dropdown and storing the data in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am dynamically adding dropdown field on click of a button using append in jquery.
A dropdown field appears on every click of this button
I want to store the data in the json form
such as ,

```
{"value":"Dropdown1",},
{"value":"Dropdown2",},
{"value":"dropdown3"}
```

Comment: 404: Question not found.

Comment: @Lain sorry was editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much information in the question, yet probably something like this:

```
var tO = {};
for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('select'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
    tO[tL[i].name || tL[i].id || i] = tL[i].value
}
```